Restore geometry changes font style
I used \newgeometry to make sure my figure fits the page, and then \restoregeometry to bring back the default margins of my project. However, I've encountered two problems.

I cannot write right below the figure when there is still some space.
For some reason, the font style changes as well.

The preamble of the document:
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.3in, rmargin=1in, tmargin=1in, bmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections, calc, positioning, arrows.meta, backgrounds, quotes,  ext.positioning-plus, % for … = of -(…)(…) and … = .5:of …
                        %   loads the positioning library
  ext.paths.ortho,      % for |- and -| shortcuts
  graphs}

\sffamily
\newgeometry{lmargin=0.1in, rmargin=0.1in, tmargin=0.4in, bmargin=1in}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=.4cm and 1.2cm,
  >=Latex, thick,
  adjust matrix area/.style args={#1#2#3}{
    insert path={([shift={(#1.25em,#2.25em)}]#3)}},
  singleline box/.style={minimum width=+7em, text depth=+.1\baselineskip},
  multiline box/.style={singleline box, minimum height=+4em, align=center},
  gray box/.style={draw, fill=gray!10},
  blue box/.style={draw, fill=black, text=white, multiline box},
  magenta box/.style={draw, fill=cyan!80!blue, text=white, singleline box},
  every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+.3em},
  scale=0.6,
  transform shape
]
\matrix[gray box] (cp) {
  \tikzset{name prefix=cp+}
  \path[nodes=blue box]
    node(Design) {Design}
    node[right=of Design] (Fabric) {Fabrication}
    node[right=of Fabric] (Assemb) {Assembly,\\Testing, and\\Packaging};
  \path[nodes=magenta box]
    node[above=of Design] (Fables) {\textbf{Fabless}}
    node[above=of Fabric] (Foundr) {\textbf{Foundry}}
    node[above=of Assemb] (OSAT)   {\textbf{OSAT}}
    node[above=of -(Fables)(OSAT)] (IDM) {\textbf{Integrated Device Manufacturer}};
  \node[above=.5:of IDM] (cp) {\textbf{Chip Production}}
    [adjust matrix area/.list={--Design.south west, +-Assemb.south east}];
  \\};
\matrix[gray box, below=of cp] (icp) {
  \tikzset{name prefix=icp+}
  \path[nodes=blue box]
    node                  (EDAC) {Electronic\\Design\\Automation and\\Core IP}
    node[right=of EDAC]   (SME)  {Semiconductor\\Manufacturing\\Equipment}
    node[right=of SME]    (Matr) {Materials};
  \node[below=.5:of SME] (icp) {\textbf{Inputs to Chip Production}}
    [adjust matrix area/.list={-+EDAC.north west, ++Matr.north east}];
  \\};
\coordinate (cpicp-west) at ($(cp.south west)!.5!(icp.north west)$)
 coordinate (cpicp-east) at ($(cp.south east)!.5!(icp.north east)$);
\node[left =of cpicp-west, blue box, font=\Large] (RandD) {\textbf{R\&D}};
\node[right=of cpicp-east, gray box, multiline box, font=\Large] (EndUse) {\textbf{End Use}};

\graph[use existing nodes, /tikz/ortho/install shortcuts]{
  cp+Design ->     cp+Fabric -> cp+Assemb ->[-|] EndUse,
  icp+EDAC  ->     cp+Design,
  icp+SME   ->     {cp+Fabric, cp+Assemb, icp+Matr},
  icp+Matr  ->     {cp+Fabric, cp+Assemb},
  RandD     ->[|-] {cp, icp}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flowchart of the semiconductor industry}
\end{figure}

\restoregeometry



do not use newgeometry for this. There are other ways to allow a larger figure on a  page.

maybe use changepage which can adjust the width of the text block temporarily? \restoregeometry and \newgeometry always start new pages. or you can lie to LaTeX and claim your image is some other size. In combination with \centering this can work OK (provided the content really does fit - you effectively turn off all the usual checks, so you have to make sure it fits yourself).

it's not clear what font you think has changed, and you have not provided an example we can run to see the issue. The \sffamily will not affect the float (unrelated to \newgeometry) as floats such as figure are designed to always use the document fomt not the font current at that point.
